# erro #1932 no phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Instalei o XAMPP for Windows 5.6.15, Apache + MariaDB + PHP + Perl. Funciona tudo bem até que "do nada" algumas tabelas aleatoriamente, ficam "em utilização".
Simplesmente não consigo mais acessá-las, continua gravando, editando e excluindo via comando PHP, porém não ficam acessíveis direto no phpMyAdmin, então não consigo saber quantos registros tem, nem exportar a tabela, nem excluir ela, enfim não consigo fazer nada direto no banco.

Segue imagem para melhor entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico pra abrir a tabela dá este erro:

> 1932 - Table 'meuBanco.minhaTabela' doesn't exist in engine

Se tento deletar mostra isso:

> 1347 - 'meuBanco.minhaTabela' is not VIEW

Se tiverem ideia do que possa ser ou já passaram por isso, desde já agradeço.
Obs1.: Já desinstalei e instalei novamente e deu o mesmo erro.
Obs2.: Usando o MySQL Workbench também apresenta mesmo problema.